# Write this expression with series & sum in terms of a single variable

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, dirac-delta

I know this is very specific, but is there a way to represent the expression

$$\frac{3}{5} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n \sum_{j = 0}^n {n \choose j} \delta_{2j - n, k}$$

in terms of the variable $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?  I think I'm just after some way to find out which values of $j,n$ and $k$ the delta function is nonzero, and then I'll be able to write the expression in terms of $k$ since the series converges.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that I'm only answering your easier question of how to get rid of the Kronecker delta. In the inner sum, the only nonzero term occurs when $2j - n = k$ and hence $j = (k+n)/2$. (There is no nonzero term if the latter quantity isn't an integer.) So the only nonzero terms in the outer sum occur when $n \equiv k \pmod{2}$. For instance, if $k$ is even, say $k = 2m$, then the sum becomes after reindexing

$$
\frac{3}{5}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{2n}\binom{2n}{m+n}
$$

(or, if you'd prefer, change the $m$ to a $k/2$ to express it in terms of $n$). The series looks similar if $k = 2m+1$:

$$
\frac{3}{5}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{m+n+1}.
$$